# Syntax error with execute a query with one to one

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have two entities:

1. `User` entity with two fields are: `id` (@id), `username`
2. `Profile` entity with two fields are: `user`(@OneToOne,targetEntity="User"), `fullname`

But when I make a query try from things I read an JPA book:

`SELECT p from Profile p where p.user.username = 'john'`

It alerts to me a message:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 55: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current [EBNF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf), the syntax you used is invalid in Doctrine 2 ORM. You will have to join the related entity as following:

```
SELECT
    p
FROM
    Profile p
JOIN
    p.user u
WHERE
    u.username = :username
```